# Converting anonymous user to a registered user

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-cli, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Angular 6 and Firebase with Angular-cli.

**The problem: I need to convert an anonymous user to a registered one, while saving all the data he put in my collections while he was a guest.**

The collections I have in Firestore Database:

**`users/uid` collection:** Has extended information about the user (age, gender etc).

**`quizes/uid/quiz/quizid` collection:** the user's (unlimited) quizes. each quiz has its own data. (answers, isFinished, finalScore etc).

Each user, both anonymous and authorized, creates information in both collections.

I need a way to convert a guest into a registered user, **so he can log back in with the data he put as a guest.**

In my case, each anonymous and registered user has two collections: "quizes" and "user":
The user collection has extended information about him (age, gender etc) and is stored in "users/uid"
The quizes collection has the quizes sorted by the UID, and is stored in: "quizes/uid/quiz/quizid" (each user can have unlimited quizes)

*The **anonymous user** should be able convert to **registered user**, using facebook / google / email&password authorization.*

Just to share a my code, this is how I do the register / login as a **registed user** with email & password:

```
  emailLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.alertSuccess)
      .catch(this.alertError);
  }

  emailRegister(email: string, password: string) {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(this.alertSuccess)
      .catch(this.alertError);
  }
```

This is how I create an **anonymous user**:

```
  guestAuth() {
    console.log('guestAuth()');
    this.loading['AUTHORIZE.AS_A_GUEST'] = true;
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously()
      .then((credential) => this.updateUserData(credential.user))
      .then(this.alertSuccess)
      .then(this.goWhereUserCameFor)
      .catch(this.alertError);
  }
```

I think I need some kind of `upgradeAnonymous()` function but I honestly don't know where to start doing so.

Any answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a great tutorial specifically for Angular:**
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular-firebase-authentication-tutorial-anonymous-auth

This tutorial recommends updating the new user with a snapshot from the anonymous user.  Just do this for all the different collections (copy with new `uid`)

The other option per the Google Docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

This is example (async/await) code JS from one of my projects (Vue not Angular but pretty basic):

```
const credential = await firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(this.form.email, this.form.password)
const response = await firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
```

The `response` should be the same as `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

The docs state:

> If the call to link succeeds, the user's new account can access the anonymous account's Firebase data.

But does not give any more information or details regarding that (which I am still trying to figure out what that means....)